# C++ Can't get Pointers to work

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having a problem using pointers in C++ and I can't figure out what it is;

I have a class called LectureNode:

```
class LectureNode
{
public:
Lecture *LecturePtr;

LectureNode(Lecture lec)
{
    LecturePtr = &lec;
}
};
```

This class's constructor works just fine.
I have another class:

```
class LectureForest
{
LectureNode *LecNode;
list<Lecture>::iterator it;

public:
LectureForest(list<Lecture> lecs)
{
    Makeset(lecs);
}

void Makeset(list<Lecture> lecs)
{
    for(it = lecs.begin(); it != lecs.end(); it++)
    {
        LecNode = LectureNode(*it); 
    }
}
```

The problem occurs at this last line. (*it) is passed to the LectureNode constructor, a LectureNode creates successfully, but then LecNode doesn't point to it, instead the debugger says bad pointer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem, the code

```
LectureNode(Lecture lec)
{
    LecturePtr = &lec;
}
```

stores a pointer to a by-value argument, a local. if that pointer is used later on then you have **Undefined Behavior** because the by-value argument doesn't exist any more.

---

one reasonable solution is to do

```
LectureNode(Lecture* const lec)
    : lecturePtr_( lec )
{}
```

where

- Passing a pointer, which is conventional when a pointer is going to be stored (and also solves the UB problem)
- Using an *initializer list* instead of assignment in the constructor body, which is a good habit (it's more general, works in more cases, and also can be more efficient)
- Using a uniform naming convention (lowercase initial character for both `lec` and `lecturePtr_`), with a common suffix convention for data members (underscore at end).

---

just a note in passing, the term "initializer list" has more than one meaning. it also refers to a curly braces list of initial values. the holy standard's term for the constructor initializer list is *mem-initializer*, but i've never heard or seen anyone using that term.

Comment: Just a heads-up: do not mix up the terms _initializer list_ and _initialization list_. You mean the latter. In addition, a reference of Lecture could be used instead, which makes a guarantee that the passed object isn't actually a null pointer.

Comment: How would I change the Makeset function to reflect your solution? Let's say going with the first one

Comment: @E_net: the terms i've used are just descriptive. which means that they mean what it sounds as if they mean. the formal terms of the holy standard (in particular *mem-initializer*) are a different kind of beast, to be used only in formal stuff. re passing a reference yes that's possible but unconventional, i think mostly because it's a bit unnatural to dereference a pointer in order to get a reference one can then take the address of (like, people mostly don't think it's worth it).

Comment: @YechielLabunskiy: you could change `LecNode = LectureNode(*it)` to `LecNode = LectureNode(new Lecture(*it))`.